# With plain JS, can I check if a class is in use?

Tags: javascript, css

Let's say I have a CSS class:

```
.foo {
  background-color: green;
}
```

And several HTML elements:

```
<div>
  Hello
</div>

<p>
  Hello 2
</p>

<h1 class="foo">
  Hello 3
</h1>
```

Is there a way to check if any specific class is in use using Javascript? So, if "foo" was being used **by any element**, I would run some code?

I've tried `*.classList.contains("foo")` and several other things, but none of them worked. How do I check this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no such thing as a CSS class. You have a CSS rule, which is part of a ruleset, which has a class selector. Are you trying to find out if it matches any element in the document no matter what the selector is? Are you trying to find out if any elements that are members of a specific class exist (CSS by the by)? Are you trying to find out if the rule it being applied to an element and not being overridden by something lower down the cascade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getElementsByClassName()` and check length of resultant list. If it is zero , none were found

```js
if(document.getElementsByClassName('foo').length){
  console.log('Found at least one')
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
</div>

<p>
  Hello 2
</p>

<h1 class="foo">
  Hello 3
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("foo").length > 0){

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

There you go buddy:

```js
var all = document.body.querySelectorAll("*");

for(var element of all){
  if (element.classList.contains("foo")){
    console.log("the elemment '" + element.nodeName + "' is using the class 'foo'");
  }
}
```

Replace the `console.log()` message with whatever you want to execute (you can even execute code on the specific element using the class)

**EDIT: A more efficient solution:**

```js
var testClass = document.body.querySelectorAll(".testClass");

if(testClass.length > 0){
  console.log("a class has been used");
}else{
  console.log("no class :(");
}
```

Comment: That's a massively inefficient approach to solving the problem. `querySelectorAll` can take a class selector.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that, and I'm editing my answer.